# Minecraft In-Game Server Connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to find out if there is a plugin or anything that will allow someone in my server to connect to another server. For example, maybe they can do '/connect IP' and it will connect them to the IP they typed in. Is this possible?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking here.  You...want a plugin that allows connecting via a commandline?

Comment: @Frank I understand that it is hard to understand... But you are right. I would prefer it to be a sign that you right click on or something and it connects you to a different server. So yes, you are right.

Comment: Not sure if this is off-topic: the OP asks for "a plugin or anything". There might be solutions to this that don't require third-party software.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open as per the [meta] posts, [Is "mod rec" really an umbrella category that we want to use? Or is it confusing the situation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797) and [The community is closing "mod rec" questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8147/4797)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to teleport to other bukkit servers without disconnecting via the pause menu and filling in the new IP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147783/how-to-teleport-to-other-bukkit-servers-without-disconnecting-via-the-pause-menu)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out Bungeecord: http://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/about-bungeecord/

Answer (score 1):

Heres a solution that is a mod which requires minecraft forge.

The mod's name is qCraft. It allows for interserver portals.

https://sites.google.com/a/elinemedia.com/qcraft/wiki/qcraft/blocks-and-items
Look at quantum portals near the bottom