# How to add /server to a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I would like to add `/server` to my server. I want my players on my server to type `/server` and have this message pop up:

```
You are connected to the Hub.

You may connect to the following servers at this time: Hub, KitPvp, CookieWars, SlowRunner
```

However I do not know how to do it. Does anyone know how I can add a `/server` command to my server?

Comment: You cannot add more commands with command blocks. You are going to need a plugin or something similar. Are you running on Bukkit?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165471/can-i-use-the-testfor-command-to-check-for-certain-words-in-chat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to teleport to other bukkit servers without disconnecting via the pause menu and filling in the new IP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147783/how-to-teleport-to-other-bukkit-servers-without-disconnecting-via-the-pause-menu)

Answer (score 2):

Use BungeeCord to create a server network. This is very complicated. Some guides:

https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bungeecord/

https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/1-8-1-9-bungeecord.392/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a bungeecord server, it is usually not to hard but it can be tricky, if you do happen to get lost their are man guides on YouTube to help you.

After you get bungeecord set up you will also need to install "slash server" in to your bungeecord plugin folder then players would be able to type /hub , /skyblock , /anything. Here is a link to the plugin https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/slashserver.75/

If u need any help at all I will be glad to help you, and all you have To do is ask me!