# How do I send a player from my minecraft server to another minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bungeecord

I am running this Minecraft server on Minehut and I want to send anyone who joins instantly to another Minecraft server which I also own, I heard you can do this with bungee cord but I don't know how exactly are you supposed to use bungee cord to do this.

Comment: Related: [How to teleport to other bukkit servers without disconnecting via the pause menu and filling in the new IP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147783/how-to-teleport-to-other-bukkit-servers-without-disconnecting-via-the-pause-menu), [Is it possible to link 2 different servers together?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266872/is-it-possible-to-link-2-different-servers-together) and their duplicates. This isn't technically a duplicate since none of the answers go into much more detail than "use BungeeCord", surprisingly.